# The views didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

I use django on linux to bulid a register website.It can't works!!

The error message:
    The view blog.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        headImg  = models.FileField(upload_to = './upload/')
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.username
```

views.py

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField()
        headImg  = forms.FileField()

def register(req): 
        if req.method == "POST":
                uf = UserForm(req.POST)
                if uf.is_valid():
                        print uf.cleaned_data['username']
                        print uf.cleaned_data['headImg'].name
                        user = User()
                        user.username = uf.cleaned_data['username']
                        user.headImg  = uf.cleaned_data['headImg']
                        user.save()
                        return HttpResponse('ok') 
        else:
                uf = UserForm()
                return render_to_response('register.html',{'uf':uf})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def register(req): 
        if req.method == "POST":
                uf = UserForm(req.POST)
                if uf.is_valid():
                        ....
                        return HttpResponse('ok') 
                # If control flow is reach here, nothing is returned.
        else:
                uf = UserForm()
                return render_to_response('register.html',{'uf':uf})
```

If an invalid `POST` request is come, the view will return nothing. (implicitly None)

Try following:

```
def register(req): 
    if req.method == "POST":
        uf = UserForm(req.POST)
        if uf.is_valid():
            ....
            return HttpResponse('ok') 
    uf = UserForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html',{'uf':uf})
```

Comment: if req.method != "POST".Shouldn't it return render_to_response?

Comment: @user2741941, Yes it does. But according to the error message, request method is POST and `us.is_valid()` is false.

Comment: I have found out what's wrong! The if sentence inside don't have a else sentence. And uf = UserForm(req.POST) should be changed into uf = UserForm(req.POST,req.FILES). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to decrease the indent of the last line. That should be caught both by the case where it is not a POST, *and* when it is a POST but the form is invalid.

Comment: I cancel a tab in the last line. It turns out "This field is required.".